# What is the difference between io:format and io:fwrite in Erlang?

Tags: syntax, io, erlang

Even in the [documentation](https://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-1), there does not seem to be any difference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`io:fwrite` was introduced as an alias for `io:format`, for symmetry with `io:fread`, but most people kept using the name `format` anyway.

Comment: Is there a source for this? When was it introduced?

Comment: @tla This happened before Erlang was released as Open Source, back in the mid 90s.